# Yarn showing key emoji

Tags: yarnpkg

While performing `yarn` in my project (which keeps failing) the yarn log is showing a key emoji () at the end of the line.

Why that? And what does it mean?

Comment: In the command line? It's probably waiting for a password, see e.g. https://superuser.com/questions/1014065/how-to-display-custom-key-icon-on-terminal-app

Comment: Yes in the command line

Comment: @jonrsharpe which password is missing? npm? github?

Comment: I'm not sure. You're asking people to guess why a key icon is being shown in logs you haven't included, so who knows?

Comment: It's exactly what u said, super thanks! 
I renew the ssh keys with GitHub, and it works.
And add it as answer here, it worth it :)